# How do I use regular expressions in PostgreSQL to remove the end of a field matching pattern?

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

How can I simplify this PostgreSQL? Basically I want to check if the fields end with 
`(1)` or just `(1)` and replace and repeat from numbers from 1-30. I assume it can be done with regular expressions somehow, but I haven't got it working.

```
UPDATE discogs.artist_meta
SET name = substr(name,0, strpos(name,' (1)'))
WHERE name LIKE '% (1)';

UPDATE discogs.artist_meta
SET name = substr(name,0, strpos(name,'(1)'))
WHERE name LIKE '%(1)';


UPDATE discogs.artist_meta
SET name = substr(name,0, strpos(name,' (2)'))
WHERE name LIKE '% (2)';

UPDATE discogs.artist_meta
SET name = substr(name,0, strpos(name,'(2)'))
WHERE name LIKE '%(2)';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. use the `regexp_replace(target, regexp, replacewith)` [function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-string.html)
2. your pattern would be something like `' ?\(([1-9]|[12][0-9]|30)\)$'`
3. i'm not exactly sure what you are trying to replace with...just removing the number? if so, replace with `''`.

Regexp explanation:

```
" ?"                 = optional space
\(                   = opening parenthesis (escaped)
([1-9]|[12][0-9]|30) = numbers 1-30
\)                   = closing parenthesis (escaped)
$                    = end of content
```

Regarding your comment:

```
update discogs.artist_meta
set name = regexp_replace(name, ' ?\(([1-9]|[12][0-9]|30)\)$', '')
where name ~ ' ?\(([1-9]|[12][0-9]|30)\)$'
```

Comment: I don't think you'll need that `$` right there. That'll cut the regex short. You need another 1-2 character before the end of the line

Comment: Can I apply that on the LIKE as well I only want to chnage rows containing said regex