# PostgreSQL trim text field with regex (or else)

Tags: regex, postgresql

I'd like to do complex substring or trim task on a field  with values like:

```
"{"itemID":["15671\/3#1#4202","15686\/4#1#4203","15687\/1#1#4203"]}"  
"{"itemID":["15671\/3#1#4204","15687\/1#1#4204"]}"  
"{"itemID":["10966\/4#1#4201"]}"
```

The desired result should look like:

```
"4202, 4203, 4203"  
"4204, 4204"  
"4201"
```

In words: last four digits before every comma (if there is) and the last 4 digits.

Even better if there is a way to distinct the values within the cell:

```
"4202, 4203"  
"4204"  
"4201"
```

I read several seemingly relevant questions, including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25490567/how-do-i-use-regular-expressions-in-postgresql-to-remove-the-end-of-a-field-matc) but found nothing close enough.

Comment: What data type is that column? Is the content always valid JSON?

Comment: 1: type is text. 2: Don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If those values are always valid JSON, you can use the following (assuming there is a primary key column in that table):

```
select t.id, string_agg(distinct right(item.id, 4), ',') as ids
from schema01.table01 t
   cross join jsonb_array_elements_text(t.the_column::jsonb -> 'itemID') as item(id)
group by t.id;
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/SUWG96428

Comment: Thank you, works wonderful in the rextester!  I cannot test it yet, cause I have to use schema.table syntax and its not compatible with this "t" abbreviation. Could you please edit your example using table name "schema01.table01" ?

Answer (score 0):

Using regex, assuming values potentially non-json, potentially don't end with 4 digits, and unnesting an array of values to simulate your table:

```sql
SELECT col, (SELECT STRING_AGG(DISTINCT r[1], ',') FROM REGEXP_MATCHES(col, '([\d]{4})"[,\]]', 'g') r)
FROM UNNEST(ARRAY[
    '{"itemID":["15671\/3#1#4202","15686\/4#1#4203","15687\/1#1#4203"]}',
    '{"itemID":["15671\/3#1#4204","15687\/1#1#4204"]}',
    '{"itemID":["10966\/4#1#4201"]}'
]::TEXT[]) AS col
GROUP BY col
```

Grouping by `col` just to have some row-identifying value to group by, a primary key would be ideal.

Result:

```
| col                                                                | string_agg |
| ------------------------------------------------------------------ | ---------- |
| {"itemID":["15671\/3#1#4202","15686\/4#1#4203","15687\/1#1#4203"]} | 4202,4203  |
| {"itemID":["15671\/3#1#4204","15687\/1#1#4204"]}                   | 4204       |
| {"itemID":["10966\/4#1#4201"]}                                     | 4201       |
```