# JSON extract multiple columns PostgreSQL

Tags: json, postgresql

I had a question earlier: [PostgreSQL trim text field with regex (or else)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58747304/postgresql-trim-text-field-with-regex-or-else) And I got a wonderful answer by a_horse_with_no_name. Now I have an additional question regarding this issue.

So here it is this rextester https://rextester.com/SUWG96428 and the goal is to have all the ids in a separate column. Is it possible at all?

Like this:

```
+---+----+-------+-------+
|   | id | ids_1 | ids_2 |
+---+----+-------+-------+
| 1 |  1 |  4202 |  4203 |
| 2 |  2 |  4204 |       |
| 3 |  3 |  4201 |       |
+---+----+-------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you can modify your query like:

```
select 
    t.id, 
    right(((the_column::json->'itemID')->>0)::varchar, 4) as col1,
    right(((the_column::json->'itemID')->>1)::varchar, 4) as col2,
    right(((the_column::json->'itemID')->>2)::varchar, 4) as col3
from the_table t;
```

[DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=0b40ae1d7a12e421b5e4b08cf785f1aa)

Comment: Dear Slava! The "distinct" thing is missing (and something else probably) in the first row `4203` should appear only once (and `4204` in the second ofcourse). I made a fiddle as well with more data for better testing: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=3334287f87ad76cd792bdc1f637b665b